# Adding a extra field in url but avoiding that field in url handling of Catalyst framework

Tags: perl, catalyst

Suppose I have a url

```
http://www.somesite.com/path/to/catalyst/controller
```

And I want to redirect this to

```
http://www.somesite.com/extra-part/path/to/catalyst/controller
```

This extra-part should only be in url, And should not be considered for URL handling of Catalyst.

I found that, we can inherit/override prepare_path method for this but I couldn't use it properly.

I found this link for that :
[Catalyst Wiki](http://wiki.catalystframework.org/wiki/wikicookbook/urlpathprefixing)

But still help needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of `lib/MyApp.pm` I have a function `prepare_path` that looks like this:

```
sub prepare_path {
  my $c = shift;

  $c->maybe::next::method( @_ ) ;
  my $base_uri_prefix = $c->config->{base_uri_prefix} ;
  my @path_chunks = split m[/], $c->request->path, -1;

  if (@path_chunks && $path_chunks[0] eq $base_uri_prefix ) {
    shift @path_chunks ;

    # Create modified request path from any remaining path chunks:
    my $path = join( '/' , @path_chunks ) || '/' ;

    # Stuff modified request path back into request:
    $c->request->path( $path ) ;
  } else {
    # Modify the path part of the URI to look as if it had a prefix:
    $c->request->uri->path( "$base_uri_prefix/" . $c->request->path ) ;
  }
}
```

And in `myapp.conf` is defined:

```
base_uri_prefix   extra-part
```

Comment: I did tried this and it didn't work...that's the problem?...the url is not changing....Also..what does $c->maybe::next::method does??      Can you explain??

Comment: @PERLDev This is not the exact code that you linked above. This `$c->maybe::next::method( @_ );` calls `prepare_path` in Catalyst base classes and works for Catalyst 5.8.

Comment: "$c->res->redirect" required instead of "$c->request->uri->path( "$base_uri_prefix/" . $c->request->path ) ;"

Comment: @PERLDev It works for me this way, but I'll try it l8r & report back.